# How to loop through an array and a date range?

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops

Here's what I need to have happen:

I have created variables that include the dates for the current week.

I have also created an array that has the sport types in it as $k => $v.

I created a javascript accordion that will open and close if clicked on. The dates of the week are used as the title of the accordion. I want to then return all the records, in their respective accordion, based on the date in the database but I also need to list those records according to sport type. So for example:

Accordion * October 2, 2013 * Accordion (when user clicks it will open and show all the records that have a game on that date listed under the sport type).

I need to echo the value of the sport type array I created if the record matches the key for the sport type. For example: if the database returns three rows of data, one having the sport type of "baseball" and two having the sport type of "MSoccer" then I need to return the records like this in a table:

BASEBALL (sport type)

VI vs. UVA close td at 6:00 PM EST

MEN'S SOCCER

VI @ Montreat at 3:30 PM EST

VI vs. St. Andrews at 4:00 PM EST

if there are no records that have a game on the date then I would just echo "no games today"

Then I need to create the next accordion item and return the records for that one where the game date matches the date for the accordion.

Here's what I have so far...just not sure where to go with it:

```
<?php
date_default_timezone_set('US/Eastern');
$today = time();
$weekMonDate = date('Y-m-d',strtotime("last Monday", $today));
$weekTuesDate = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('+1 days', strtotime($weekStartDate)));
$weekWedDate = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('+2 days', strtotime($weekStartDate)));
$weekThursDate = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('+3 days', strtotime($weekStartDate)));
$weekFriDate = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('+4 days', strtotime($weekStartDate)));
$weekSatDate = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('+5 days', strtotime($weekStartDate)));
$weekSunDate = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('+6 days', strtotime($weekStartDate)));

$sport = array(
    "Baseball" => 'BASEBALL',
    "MSoccer" => 'MEN\'S SOCCER',
    "MBasketball" => 'MEN\'S BASKETBALL',
);

foreach ($sport as $k => $v) {

$sql    = 'SELECT gametime, conference, scrimmage, exhibition, gamedate,  homeschool,  visitorschool, homelivestatsurl, notes, gamestatus, homescore, visitorscore, score, record, sporttype FROM schedule WHERE WEEKOFYEAR(gamedate)=WEEKOFYEAR(NOW())  ORDER BY gamedate';
$result = mysql_query($sql, $link);

if (!$result) {
echo "DB Error, could not query the database\n";
echo 'MySQL Error: ' . mysql_error();
exit;
}
?>
<?php
    mysql_data_seek($result, 0);
    $day = ' ';
    $sport = ' ';
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
 if (date("d", strtotime($row['gamedate'])) !== $day) {
    $day=date("d", strtotime($row['gamedate'])); ?>
?>
```

Comment: You should try to synthesize your problem. Instead of explaining your whole problem, try to focus and what you are really trying to accomplish in programming terms.

Comment: It'd be easier for us if you'd show your work.

Comment: Here's what I have so far...just not sure where to go with it:

Comment: Where is the data coming from? Are you using a MySQL server, and ASP.Net, for example?

Comment: I'm using MySQL server and PHP. I posted what I have so far but I'm stuck on where to go with it.